# Looking for a way to open a shell inside a running Linux Subsystem on Windows

Tags: powershell, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is there a way to open an interactive shell inside a running Windows Subsystem for Linux process? I am not planning to do anything there, I'm just learning docker right now, so I am investigating some things to gain a better understanding.

If I understand it right, Docker Desktop starts two machines on my PC:

```
PS C:\Users\basti> wsl.exe -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
```

Since it is running locally, I wonder if there is a simple way to open a shell inside it, or connect to it using ssh.

Probably something similar like connecting to a Container with `docker exec -ti my-container sh`, but connect to the whole subsystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a shell inside `docker-desktop` with:

```
wsl -d docker-desktop
```

Comment: This worked for docker-desktop, but with docker-desktop-data it fails for me, any Idea how I can fix mounting/path issues like `<3>WSL (9) ERROR: CreateProcessParseCommon:708: Failed to translate C:\Users\seb_s` without breaking docker desktop? Is this even supposed to work?

Comment: You cannot run a shell in docker-desktop-data because it has a 0 byte /init.

Comment: Thank you! This answers my questions. With the 0 byte detail, I also found this related post: [What is the docker-desktop-data distro used for when running docker desktop with the WSL 2 engine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61396989/4126424)